# JUnit - Return a mocked object from a type cast

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, casting, mockito

My code looks something like this:

```
ClassB objB = (ClassB) objA;
int z = objB.ClassBMethod();

int y = objA.ClassAMethod();
```

Currently my unit test looks like this:

```
ClassA mockClassA = mock(ClassA.class);
when(mockClassA.ClassAMethod()).thenReturn(1);
```

How would I mock `objA`'s cast to `ClassB` so that I can mock the `ClassBMethod()`?

Answer (score 2):

I really hope `ClassB` is a subclass of `ClassA`... Try this:

```
ClassA mockB = mock(ClassB.class);
```

This will give you a mocked object that is really an instance of `ClassB`, but you treat it as a `ClassA` and then can successfully do the cast.

Comment: Will this allow me to mock out both ClassA and ClassB methods?

Comment: Best way to find out is to *try it*.

Comment: I should've asked: "should it allow me to mock out both ClassA and ClassB methods?" Because it doesn't.

Comment: Can you elucidate - either expand this question or open a new one - and be specific about what you think it should do and what it is actually doing. Right now I don't really understand what the problem is.